# Java cannot find symbol errors even though class and parameters has been defined?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, hashmap, parameter-passing

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong with this: Currently testing the `StringDirective` class, which is supposed to parse the input string for the name of the String variable to be created. I was thinking I've set the `TPLString` class up correctly but get a whole boatload of cannot find symbol errors on multiple lines-- are the parameters I passed in wrong? This code is supposed to parse a String, split it in two parts, parse it for a String variable name, and then assign it an empty string as a value for now, and then store the information about the variable's name and value in a `HashMap`.

```
public class StringStatement implements Directive
{   /** StringStatement implements the STRING keyword as defined in class TPLString.
    *   This keyword declares a String variable.
    *   A declared String is empty when first instantiated.
    */

    public void execute(String[] parts)
    {
        //instantiate a TPLString
        String temp=parts[1];
        String[] placeholder = temp.split("[\\s+]");
        String name=placeholder[0];
        String value;



        variables.addVariable(name, value);//add variable to variables hashmap
    }
}
```

//variable classes

```
abstract class TPLVariable
{
    String name;
    TPLVariable(String s)
    {
        name = s;
    }
}

class TPLInt extends TPLVariable
{
    int intValue;
    TPLInt(String s, int v)
    {
        super(s);
        intValue=v;
    }
}

class TPLString extends TPLVariable
{
    String stringValue;
    TPLString(String s, String str)
    {
        super(s);
        stringValue=str;
    }

}
```

//add to variables HashMap

```
class TPLVariables  
{  
    private Map<String, TPLVariables> variables = new HashMap<String, TPLVariables>();  

    public void addVariable(String name, String value)  
    {  
// Parses the declaration String, create a TPLVariable of the appropriate type   
// and add it to the map using the variable name as the key 


        if(value.charAt(0)=='"')
        {

            TPLString stringDeclaration= new TPLString(name, value);
            variables.put(name, TPLString(name, value));
            System.out.println(name+ " hex0");//debug
            System.out.println(value+ " hex1");//debug
        }
        else
        {

            TPLInt integerDeclaration= new TPLInt(name, value);
            variables.put(name, TPLInt(name, value));
            System.out.println(name+ " hex2");//debug
            System.out.println(value+ " hex3");//debug
        }


    }
```

Comment: What specific errors are you getting? Are you including the needed files?

Comment: Yeah, reckon I have-- the only code not included is the original methods for parsing the String into a format [keyword+ values]; that's for the first HashMap that maps to the Directive classes e.g. the StringDirective class above.

Comment: @cdeszaq The first error that's a big concern is the one where it says it can't find the TPLString in the line `variables.put(name,TPLString(name, value));`

Comment: I see no package or import declarations -- are all your classes in the default package?

Comment: @Tom G Yes. left off the import declarations since those are fine: the import declarations are 
`import.java.io.*;`
`import java.util.*;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TPLString(name, value)` is not a correct syntax.

If you want a new TPLVariable, you should add new keyword before it.

```
variables.put(name, new TPLString(name, value));
```

If you want to reference previous variable you declare, you should use it's name

```
TPLString stringDeclaration= new TPLString(name, value);
variables.put(name, stringDeclaration);
```

I suggest you can follow [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) principle to post question next time